# What does this error mean in surf of three variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mesh

I am trying to make an arbitrary function that contains three variables: X, Y and T, which are of the same length, 201.

I run

```
[X,Y,T] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10, -10:0.1:10, 0:0.5:100); 
FF = @(x,y,t) exp( -(x - 0.5).^2 - (y - 0.5).^2 ) / 0.1^2 .* sin(pi * t); 
surf(FF(X,Y,T))
```

I get

> Error using  *  Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be
>   scalar. To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.
>
> Error in @(x,y,t)exp(-(x-0.5).^2-(y-0.5).^2)/0.1^2*sin(pi*t)

I know that this works

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10, -10:0.1:10); 
FF = @(x,y) exp( -(x - 0.5).^2 - (y - 0.5).^2 ) / 0.1^2; 
surf(FF(X,Y))
```

creating Gaussian Bell curve.
I want to add time dependence to this curve, but unsuccessful.

**How can you make an arbitrary function of three variables and surf it in Matlab?**

Comment: If you get out sin(pi*T) the matrix is 201x201x201. The result of the @(x,y) is 201x201, so matrix dimensions aren't equal.

Comment: And make sure you copy the right thing because in your function you do `.* sin(pi*t)` and into your error it only `*`

Comment: You want to plot in _four_ dimensions??

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to make video in 2D, where **T** is time, and X and Y physical coordinates.

Comment: @Masi But that's not `surf`. Perhaps with `movie`?

Comment: @LuisMendo I think it is not movie. I have probably missunderstood the point of meshgrid. I think the time should be outside of meshgrid, so time separately T = 0:0.5:100. Then, just run the surf command in a loop as a function of time, t. So this way video.

Comment: @Masi. I see. Yes, you can do it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you overwrote pi to be a matrix?  That would give you the error you're getting. Here's an example of plotting the function at different time points:

```
[X,Y,T] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10, -10:0.1:10, 0:0.5:100);
FF = @(x,y,t) exp( -(x - 0.5).^2 - (y - 0.5).^2 ) / 0.1^2 .* sin(pi * t);
Z = FF(X,Y,T);

figure

subplot(3,1,1)
surf(Z(:,:,1))
title('t = 1')

subplot(3,1,2)
surf(Z(:,:,2))
title('t = 2')

subplot(3,1,3)
surf(Z(:,:,3))
title('t = 3')
```

[image: surf of function at different time points]